# GVFS Locations Not Available In ~/.gvfs

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, cifs, rhel6

So, I can mount GVFS locations correctly (specifically CIFS) either from the Gnome "Places" menu, or via the command line `gvfs-mount`, but the filesystem is not mounted in the expected location; `~/.gvfs`.  In fact, running the `mount` command does not list any GVFS filesystem at all.

- This is reproducible for non-root users while the root user behaves as expected.
- Strace reveals a permissions error for the user mounting the filesystem for the path /home/username/.gvfs.
- Ownership and permissions are correct and there are no extended attributes for the path as revealed by `lsattr`.
- Also, /root/.gvfs and /home/username/.gvfs are on the same filesystem.
- All packages are current.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

After reading [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61196/why-do-my-gvfs-mounts-not-show-up-under-gvfs), I found that `gvfs-fuse-daemon` was not started and tried to run it manually.

> $ /usr/libexec/gvfs-fuse-daemon ~/.gvfs
>   fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied

So, the permission denied I saw in `strace` was on `/bin/fusermount`, not the destination path `/home/username/.gvfs`.  However, `/bin/fusermount` is setuid so unprivileged users should be able to run it as root.  I am not fond of mucking with permissions but gave `/bin/fusermount` o+rx to test.  It executes and fixes the problem.  **So, why does this daemon have to be ran manually for non-root users?  It seems to be an Ubuntu issue as well, but that went unanswered in the other question.**

EDIT: 7/10/2012

I learned that instead of giving o+rx to /bin/fusermount I should add the user to the fuse group.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 12.10 the paths were changed:

```
$ mount |grep gvfs
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/pcm/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=pcm)
```